# I work there/I'm working there/It's where I work

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

A man gets into a Taxi and says this:

> Man: Hi. Could you please drive me to the Chrysler Building. **I work there.** We're having an office party tonight.

Is **I work there** natural? Or would **I'm working there** or **it's where I work** be more natural in this context?

Answer (score 1):

*I work there* vs. *I'm working there* is a difference of meaning. Usually, and I believe for your intended meaning, the first is correct. You might use the second if you were working there temporarily, for example.

*I work there* vs. *it's where I work* is a difference of style. They both mean more or less the same thing, so pick the one you like the sound of.

Answer (score 1):

"I work there" is natural (it suggests that it is a reasonably permanent job).

It strikes me as rather unnatural to tell this to a taxi driver. You aren't friends with the driver, so it seems odd to tell them why you are going to a place. Perhaps if you feel you need to explain why you are (for example) wearing fancy-dress. but not otherwise.